# What can cause an ARM MemManage exception with all bits in the MMSFR register zero?

Tags: debugging, exception, arm, stm32f4

I'm working on Ethernet code on an STM32F429 ARM Cortex M4 device and running into a situation where I'm getting an MemManage exception where the cause is proving very difficult to track down. From what I understand, the MemManage exception is caused by some violation of the MPU such as trying to execute code in the protected register space at 0xE0000000 and above.  Cortex M4 documentation I've read indicates the reason for the exception should be captured in the MMSFR register bits and that the address of the error may be captured in the MMFAR register in certain circumstances.

What frustrating me is that MemManage exception is being generated with all bits in the MMSFR register zero. I'm executing a breakpoint instruction just as the exception handler is entered so I'm pretty sure the MMSFR is not being accidentally cleared.  Furthermore, no where in my code am I even using the MPU and it should be in its default state on power-up. Finally, I can purposely create a MemManage exception elsewhere in my code and the MMSFR bits correctly identify the issue I triggered.  Unwinding the stack from the exception, the only thing unusual thing about the PC is that it's in the middle of code that is called early on to initialize the RTOS, but should not be executing later when the exception occurs.  I'm trying to determine how the PC got to the value it did, but it's proving difficult to isolate.

Does someone have some ideas as to why the the MemManage exception might occur without the MMSFR bits being set?  Or, suggestions for techniques to better understand the circumstances that occur in my code just before the exception occurs.

Answer (score 4):

I finally tracked down the issue.  It was code executing a callback function within a structure, but the structure pointer was a null pointer.  The offset of the callback function within the structure corresponded to the offset of the MemManager exception handler in the vector table from address zero.  Thus, the MemManager handler was not being called via an exception, but rather a simple function call.  This was why the stack looked confusing to me -- I was expecting to see a an exception stack frame rather than a simple function call stack frame.

The clue to me was the exception state bits in the PSR ([8-0]) being all zeros (thanks to the [suggestion from cooperised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52234511/605307)) which indicates my MemManager exception was not actually being called as an exception.  I then backtracked from there to understand what code was responsible for calling the handler as a function call.  My flawed assumption was that the only way the MemManager handler could be reached was via an exception -- with the PSR value and non-exception stack frame being the major clues that I was ignoring.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer.  Throwing some upvotes in the direction of the answers or comments that helped you to your solution would be appreciated too!  :-)

Answer (score 3):

My instinct (not necessarily accurate!) is that something's not right here.  There's no reason that the MemManage exception should not accurately log the reason for its invocation, and your mention of the PC having been somewhere it shouldn't have been suggests that whatever's wrong went wrong well before the exception entry.  On that basis I think you'll learn more by identifying *where* the exception takes place than by trying to deduce the cause from the exception type.

I'd start by checking the value in LR at the point you've identified that the exception takes place.  This won't necessarily tell you where the PC corruption took place, but it'll tell you where the last `BL` was issued prior to the problem, so it might help put bounds on where the problem might be.  You might also find it helpful to check the exception state bits in the PSR ([8-0]) to confirm the type of the fault.  (MemManage is 0x004.)

Comment: Thanks for reminding me about the exception state bits in the PSR to confirm the exception type and using the LR to identify the last branch prior to the exception.  I agree that something isn't right and the MMSFR should log the reason for the exception as it works fine if I manually trip the exception.  There is most likely a false assumption on my part about what is leading up to the MemManage exception handler being called, I just need to figure out what my false assumption might be.

Answer (score 0):

Double-check that the exception you're getting is actually MemManage and not something else (e.g. if you're using a shared handler for several exception types). Another possibility is that you're getting an imprecise fault and the information about the original fault has been discarded. From [FreeRTOS debugging guide](https://www.freertos.org/Debugging-Hard-Faults-On-Cortex-M-Microcontrollers.html):

> ARM Cortex-M faults can be precise or imprecise. If the `IMPRECISERR`
>   bit (bit 2) is set in the BusFault Status Register (or `BFSR`, which
>   is byte accessible at address `0xE000ED29`) is set then the fault is
>   imprecise.
>
> ...
>
> In the above example, turning off write buffering by setting the
>   `DISDEFWBUF` bit (bit 1) in the Auxiliary Control Register (or
>   `ACTLR`) will result in the imprecise fault becoming a precise fault,
>   which makes the fault easier to debug, albeit at the cost of slower
>   program execution.

Comment: I thought the imprecise bit was for the HardFault exception, but I'll double-check to see if it could also apply to the MemManage exception.  I'll see if turning off write buffer yields any difference information captured at the time of the exception.